# Erasing last element from a set in C++

Tags: c++, c++17, std, reverse-iterator

```
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>
    #define FIN ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);cin.tie(0);cout.tie(0)
    #define SZ(s) int(s.size())
    using namespace std;
    typedef long long ll;
    int main()
    {
        FIN;
        set<ll>s;
        ll N, M;
        cin >> N >> M;
        ll x;
        for(ll i = 0; i < N+M; i++)
        {
            cin >> x;
            if(x==-1)
            {
                auto x = *s.rbegin();
                cout<<x<<'\n';
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                s.erase( --s.end() ); // --s.end() when replaced with s.rbegin(), gives an error
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            }
            else
            {
                s.insert( x );
            }
        }
        
    }
```

in the code between the horizontal lines, I am trying to erase last element from the set.

when  I write ***s.erase( s.rbegin( ) )***    instead of ***s.erase( --s.end( ) )*** , it gives me a compilation error saying:

```
 **error: no matching function for call to ‘std::set<long long int>::erase(std::set<long long int>::reverse_iterator)’
   20 |    s.erase( s.rbegin() );**
```

*arent s.rbegin() and --s.end() pointing to the same element?*

Comment: `s.rbegin()` and `--s.end()` *refer* to the same element, but they have different types. This question is not specific to `set`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

std::set::rbegin returns a **reverse_iterator**, which technically points to the same thing, yet the set doesn't have an erase method that receives a reverse_iterator as an argument.

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't work, ultimately, aren't they two pointers pointing to the same thing? The input expected by the function is an iterator pointing to an element in the array, isn't it?

Comment: @RamPrabodhInduri They aren't pointers. They are iterators, and they have different types. One is `iterator` which the function accepts and the other is `reverse_iterator` which is a completely different type from `iterator`.

Comment: Okay, got it, thank you, I was under an assumption that iterators were like pointers.

Comment: Iterators *act like* pointers (in many ways). They are *not* identical to pointers.

Comment: @RamPrabodhInduri Iterators are pointer-like in that, by design, their interfaces share some similarities with pointers. The purpose is that some containers can use pointers as iterators if the implementer chooses.

Comment: @molbdnilo pointers need not always point to an array, just any memory location.

Comment: @molbdnilo apologies, my bad. That was a sub-conscious mistake.

Answer (score 2):

`reverse_iterator` is not implemented the same as `iterator`. The logical and physical address for an `iterator` are the same but for `reverse_iterator`, the logical and physical address are not the same. For example: `s.end()` and `s.rbegin()` have the same physical address but `*s.end()` will give you an error but `*s.rbegin()` will give you the last value of the container `s`.

The code below will make things clear:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    set<int> S{ 1, 2, 3 };
    
    set<int>::iterator itr = S.find(2);
    cout << *itr << endl;

    set<int>::reverse_iterator r_itr(itr);
    cout << *r_itr << endl;

    cout << itr._Ptr << ' ' << r_itr.base()._Ptr << endl;

    //S.erase(r_itr);       // ERROR!
    S.erase(r_itr.base());

    for (int e : S)
        cout << e << ' ';
}
```

On my machine, it produced the following output:

> ```
> 2
> 1
> 00F85DA8 00F85DA8
> 1 3
> ```